# Tomcat - Deleting temp and work directory solved a classpath issue - But why?

Tags: java, tomcat, xerces

Yesterday a production deployment went wrong. After the deployment the marshalling for a soap request throws this error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xerces/jaxp/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendarImpl$Parser
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl.newXMLGregorianCalendar(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$12.parse(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:568)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$12.parse(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:544)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.TransducedAccessor$CompositeTransducedAccessorImpl.parse(TransducedAccessor.java:230)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.LeafPropertyLoader.text(LeafPropertyLoader.java:50)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.text(UnmarshallingContext.java:499)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.text(InterningXmlVisitor.java:78)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.processText(SAXConnector.java:166)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.endElement(SAXConnector.java:139)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:240)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:266)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:235)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:266)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:235)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:266)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:235)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.scan(DOMScanner.java:112)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:309)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:292)
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:127)
at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.unmarshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:746)
at org.springframework.ws.support.MarshallingUtils.unmarshal(MarshallingUtils.java:62)
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate$3.extractData(WebServiceTemplate.java:413)
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:616)
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555)
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:390)
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:383)
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:373)
```

The rest of the application runs without error. Only this marshalling went wrong. We had two tomcats on different linux servers. And on both servers we got this error. We tried to start and stop the server, But no effect.

After frustrating hours we found a solution. We deleted the temp and work direcotry of tomcat and now after restarting every thing works fine.

But why works this for both servers? What does deleting temp and work direcotry dealing with a classpaht issue?

Comment: What's your tomcat version? We had issues like these and it seemes to me things got better with Tomcat 9.

Comment: We have tomcat 7.0.52. But we will soon upgrade to tomcat 8